# Where are notes stored in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, hard-drive, notes.app

I ha a hard drive that died recently in my macbook, I've replaced the hard drive etc so no issues there. Unfortunately, it appears I wasn't backing up the notes app to iCloud, and I really need to get some back...

I've managed to get the hard drive spinning in a usb dock that I have so I can access it, but I don't know where notes was storing it's data. Any ideas?

Comment: I have a very similar problem due to a simple migration to `Mountain Lion`. Everything related to my previous notes is still in place here:
`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/`.
My question is: "From this directory tree, how could I recover the possibility to read all my previous notes?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/CoreData/ExternalRecords/`.

You can probably just copy the whole `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/` folder from the old installation.